# Оптимизация проигрывания нескольких видео на странице react, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть страница с анализом по пользователям, куда подгружается основное видео, у которого `controls = true`, и видео ( записи с вебкамер ), их может быть от 1 до 15.

Проигрывание видео с вебкамер запускается вместе с основным видео, `play`, `pause` и `timeupdate` связаны через управление основным видео. Проблема в том, что если маленьких видео 2-5, то проигрывается все без лагов, но если больше, то все начинает жутко тормозить.

Как оптимизировать запуск видео, чтобы все без тормозов проигрывалось? Пробовал поиграться с `setTimeout` и промисами, но ничего не помогло, возможно я что-то делал не так, т.к. с такой задачей столкнулся впервые. За любые мысли и предложения буду очень благодарен! [image: как это выглядит]

Comment: Поставить железо помощьнее, 15 видео файлов с современных full hd камер - тяжело компьютеру декодировать

Comment: Во время проигрывания видео, внутри страницы исполняются какие либо скрипты? Надо так же отедельно помнить, что JS это однопоточный язык и если у вас на каждое видео еще какой либо скрипт крутится, то возможно это может приводить к торможениям

Comment: Вариант с хорошим железом это самый простой способ решения)

Да, про однопоточность знаю, поэтому и пытался с event loop поиграться.

Comment: Тут надо смотреть, что там у вас происходит, что и как работает. поискать тяжелые скрипты и вынести их например в вэбворкер